# PHP PDO: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -303 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -303 conversion error from string

Tags: php, pdo, firebird, firebird1.5

I'm connecting to a Firebird 1.5 Database with PHP5.5's PDO library with the following code

```
public function getProductByKod($kod)
{
    $exec = $this->getPdo()->prepare(
        "SELECT KOD, NEV, CICSOP, AR0, AR1 FROM CIKK WHERE KOD = :KOD"
    );
    $exec->bindParam(':KOD', trim($kod), \PDO::PARAM_STR, 15);
    $exec->execute();
    return $exec->fetch();
}
```

the `$kod` is a string, and the firebird column `KOD` is a `VARCHAR(15)`

if i write anysort of string inside the `$kod` variable, it gives me this error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -303 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -303 conversion error from string
```

when the variable is empty, or its an integer it works.

I have no idea why it is doing this.

**EDIT:** [image: KOD column in DbVisualizer]

[image: KOD column in terminal]

**EDIT2:** i installed FBscanner on a windows server and watched what kind of SQl was sent to the server and i found out that the SQL was different!

```
SELECT AZON, CEG, ELONEV, VEZNEV, KERNEV, BEOSZT, HIVTEL, HIVTEL2, FAX, EMAIL, MOBIL, CEGIRSZ, CEGVAROS, CEGUTCA" FROM CEGTEL WHERE AZON = 'teszt'
```

and this is a different SQL entirely! This in from this function:

```
public function getPartnerConnectionsbyAzon($id)
{
    $exec = $this->getPdo()->prepare(
        "SELECT AZON, CEG, ELONEV, VEZNEV, KERNEV, BEOSZT, HIVTEL,"
        . "HIVTEL2, FAX, EMAIL, MOBIL, CEGIRSZ, CEGVAROS, CEGUTCA"
        . " FROM CEGTEL WHERE AZON = :AZON"
    );

    $exec->bindParam(':AZON', $id, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $exec->execute();
    $return =  $exec->fetch();

    $exec->closeCursor();

    return $return;
}
```

and i read that some drivers need closing params, that's why i put the `closeCursor` there but it still doesn't work!

Comment: That error suggests that `KOD` is not a `VARCHAR` but another type instead (most likely a numeric type). Please post the DDL of the table.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i updated the post with two pictures that both shows that in the DB the `KOD` column is indeed a `VARCHAR`.

Comment: @RyanVincent The Same error is given with `bindValue` as well. and removed the trim. same error.

Comment: I would try the Firebird Trace API to see what the actual SQL looked like.  My guess is that the string was not parameterized, or escaped properly.

Comment: @IsraelLopez there isnt any trace API for firebird 1.5 and fbhook is windows only and the server runs on linux...

Comment: I managed to found why the error was occurring, but i fon't know why. I updated the question.

Comment: In the query you show in your second edit, the WHERE is `azon = 'teszt'`, but you declare azon as int; which seems to suggest that `$id` has a string value, not int.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I know thatz the `getPartnerConnectionsbyAzon`'s `AZON` is int, and that query works as well, but that's not the problem. The problem is that when i run the `getProductByKod` function, the firebird gets the `getPartnerConnectionsbyAzon`'s SQL with the `$kod` as the `:AZON`. And this is very weird.

Comment: Found the error...basickly, i was an idiot. the mai file that uses this, has two instance, and i was using/looking at the wrong one. So yeah itsmy fault. Sorry and thank you for your time who helped me!